# Oozie action is going to next action thought the action status is Failed

Tags: oozie

I am running a Oozie workflow. I have a Fork action in that workflow. Sometimes i am observing that thought an action in Fork Status is failed, but the the flow is going to Joining and completing the flow till that end.

Can someone please let me know in what cases the above scenario occurs.

Thanks.